# Why is the implementation of IIf different in Visual Basic and FreeBasic?

Tags: vba, vb.net, vb6

In FreeBasic, `IIf (A, B, C)` is equivalent to `A ? B : C` in C/C++/Java/C#, `If (A, B, C)` in VB.NET, and `B if A else C` in python. However, in VB6, Office VBA and VB.NET, `IIf (A, B, C)` is equivalent to this C++ code:

```
bool a = A;
auto b = B;
auto c = C;
a ? b : c;
```

As a result, `IIf` works differently in Visual Basic and FreeBasic. For example,

```
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
x = 0
y = IIf (x <> 0, 12 \ x, 0)
```

works normally in FreeBasic, but will throw an exception in Visual Basic. That is because in Visual Basic this code is equivalent to the following C++ code:

```
int x, y;
x = 0;
bool a = (x != 0);
auto b = 12 / x;
auto c = 0;
y = a ? b : c;
```

In VB.NET, using `If` will do the same thing as using `IIf` in FreeBasic. For example,

```
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
x = 0
y = If (x <> 0, 12 \ x, 0)
```

in VB.NET will not throw exception.

The question is: Why does `IIf (A, B, C)` in VB6/VBA evaluate both `B` and `C`, not selecting one expression to evaluate depending on the value of expression `A`?

Answer (score 6):

`IIf` is a function. It works like any other function. It doesn't know anything about the expressions used to generate its arguments; only their values. Any expressions you write in your code to pass to `IIf` are evaluated first, just as they would be for any other method call.

VB.NET added an `If` operator in 2008. Because it's an operator, it's behaviour is baked into the language and short-circuiting is part of that, just as it is part of the behaviour of the ternary operator (`?:`) in C-based languages.

Answer (score 4):

Only the FreeBASIC developers can answer this in the affirmative, but here is some plausible speculation:

- VB.NET strives to be backwards-compatible to VBA/VB6. The (non-short-circuiting) `IIf` function already existed in VBA/VB6. Thus, making it short-circuiting would break backwards-compatibility (consider `IIf(x, SomeMethodAWithSideEffects(), SomeMethodBWithSideEffects()`). Thus, they opted to create a new operator `If(...)` instead.¹
- FreeBASIC, on the other hand, never claimed/tried to be compatible to VBA/VB6, just to QuickBASIC: Consider, for example, their object-oriented features, which have *completely* different syntax. QuickBASIC never had a `IIf` function, so they could use the keyword with slightly different semantics without having to worry about backwards-compatibility.

Now, the obvious follow-up question is: Why doesn't VBA/VB6's `IIf` operator short-circuit? Again, I can only speculate, bit I assume that they made `IIf` non short-circuiting for *consistency*. It would have been surprising for a Basic dialect to have something that *looks like* a regular function (e.g. `IIf(a, b, c)`) suddenly to have short-circuiting behavior. But, again, that's just an educated guess. Unless one of the original developers accidentally sees this question, I'm not sure we're going to get an authoritative answer.

---

¹ In the first Beta version of the .NET Framework, they changed `And` and `Or` to be logical short-circuiting operators and introduced new `BitAnd`/`BitOr` operators for the original VBA/VB6 behavior. They had to revert that change in the RTM version and introduce the new `AndAlso`/`OrElse` operators instead, to avoid breaking backwards-compatibility.

Comment: In VB.NET `And` and `Or` are bitwise operators, equivalent to `&` and `|` in C-based languages.

Comment: The mathematical functions in VB6 and VB.NET are completely different: e.g. `Sqr` in VB6 is `Math.Sqrt` in VB.NET

Comment: @stanchcorder6: True, but I'd argue that `IIf` is much more common in VBA/VB6 than `Sqr`. And it seems that they even special-cased the compiler error if you use `Sqr` in VB.NET code: [Compilation error (line 5, col 0): 'Sqr' is not declared. Function has moved to the 'System.Math' class and is named 'Sqrt'.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NunzsZ).

Comment: @stanchcorder6, in VB.NET, `And` and `Or` are BOTH bitwise and Boolean operators, just as `&` and `|` are in C#. In VB.NET, `And` and `Or` are non-short-circuiting Boolean operators and `AndAlso` and `OrElse` are short-circuiting Boolean operators. Similarly, in C#, `&` and `|` are non-short-circuiting Boolean operators and `&&` and `||` are short-circuiting Boolean operators.

Comment: In VBA, `IIf` is not an operator, it's a library function.  Thus, it should be obvious why it's not short-circuiting.

Comment: @Craig: I think that argument is backwards: The VBA/VB developers *could* have implemented `IIf` as a (short-circuiting) operator instead of a function, but they chose not to. Hence, the fact that `IIf` is a function is a *result* of their choice to make it non-short-circuiting, not the other way around.

Comment: Point taken.  Beyond consistency (which you mention) I would also add economy; it's a lot cheaper to implement something as a library function than an operator.

Comment: @user18387401 Using bitwise operator where logical operator should be used may cause unexpected problem. For example, users of Chromebook are unable to login after Chrome OS was updated to version 91 just because Google mistook logical and operator `&&` for bitwise and operator `&`.

Comment: @stanchcorder6: Indeed, but the Boolean type in VBA/VB6 was explicitly designed so that the same operator could be used for logical and bitwise And/Or.

Comment: @Heinzi Bitwise and/or operator and logical and/or operator are same in VB6 and VBA (depending on the data type of the operands), but they are different in VB.NET and FreeBasic as in C-based languages: `And`/`Or` are bitwise and/or operators in VB.NET and FreeBasic like `&`/`|` in C-based languages, while `AndAlso`/`OrElse` are logical and/or operators in VB.NET and FreeBasic like `&&`/`||` in C-based languages. Python uses `and`/`or` as logical and/or operators and `&`/`|` as bitwise and/or operators.

Comment: @stanchcorder6, The Microsoft documentation literally states that `And`, `Or`, `&` and `|` are both logical and bitwise operators in VB.NET and C# respectively. Maybe you should read something before making definitive statements that are false.

Comment: In VB6 `A() And B()` order of execution is undefined the way `a() & b()` order of execution is undefined in C/C++ (not sure about VB.Net). For the logical operator in `a() && b()`  the order of execution is obviously clearly defined (because of the short-circuit). Both of these (order and short-circuit) cannot be emulated in VB6.

Comment: @wqw: Do you have a source for that? I'm pretty sure execution order is deterministically left-to-right in VB6/VBA.

Comment: @Heinzi The onus is on you to find any clear documentation that execution order of evaluation of logical operators in VB6 is deterministic. VB.Net has short-circuit operators which bring some sort of determinism. [Here](https://github.com/twinbasic/twinbasic/issues/1040) is a discussion on p-code vs native code order of execution in VB6. I've been bitten by [heisenbugs](https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket/commit/793ff42f1503a97d0fb8826e05ec79a2e99a5556) In Real Life (tm) too because of compiler emitting a conjunction evaluation in right-to-left order.